# Validating an API request in Laravel 5.1

Tags: validation, api, exception, laravel-5.1

I am creating a simple api using laravel 5.1 to create a row in a table and return the id of the newly created row.

I am able to do so, but when it comes to validating I am not sure what to do.

e.g.
*transaction_request table*
`id|order_id|customer_id|amount`

validation rules for order_id and customer_id is just required

my uri to request this is http://localhost:8000/api/v1/transactionRequests?order_id=123&customer_id=&amount=3300

note that customer_id is not defined. user is returned with following json.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "GEN-WRONG-ARGS",
    "http_code": 400,
    "message": "{\"customer_id\":[\"The customer_id field is required.\"]}"
    }
}
```

See the message: with those '\', How do I fix that. I know, it is because, I use following validation method in my controller that throws the exception

```
public function validateRequestOrFail($request, array $rules, $messages = [], $customAttributes = [])
{
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        throw new Exception($validator->messages());
    }
}
```

and I use catch to deal with it as following

```
try {
        if(sizeof(TransactionRequest::$rules) > 0)
            $this->validateRequestOrFail($request, TransactionRequest::$rules);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return $this->response->errorWrongArgs($e->getMessage());

    }
```

errorWrongArgs is defined as following

```
public function errorWrongArgs($message = 'Wrong Arguments')
{
    return $this->setStatusCode(400)->withError($message, self::CODE_WRONG_ARGS);
}

public function withError($message, $errorCode)
{
    return $this->withArray([
        'error' => [
            'code' => $errorCode,
            'http_code' => $this->statusCode,
            'message' => $message
        ]
    ]);
}
```

I want the response to be clean as following (btw i am using ellipsesynergie/api-response library and not the default response class, because I am using chrisbjr/api-guard)

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "GEN-WRONG-ARGS",
    "http_code": 400,
    "message": {
             "customer_id": "The customer_id field is required."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return $this->response->errorWrongArgs(json_decode($e->getMessage(),true));` I used json_decode and I get "customer_id": ["The customer_id field is required."]. The problem is in the way messages are stored in $validator->messages() which is a MessageBag object, but I am not sure how to convert it to the format suitable for json response.

Comment: That said, is there a need to give such specific message in an api response, can I do with one simple message like "validation failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in my understanding of what `$validator->messages()` returns, it returns a `MessageBag` object which is more like a Json object. Where as `Exception()` expects a String message. Thus it treats the Json as a String by escaping quote character as \". Solution to this is I pass the Json string to Exception method but after I catch it I convert the Json String to an array using json_decode, which is then taken by my response class.

```
throw new Exception($validator->messages());

return $this->response->errorWrongArgs(json_decode($e->getMessage(),true));
```